# "AxiosError: Network Error" in the field of axios post request with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

Actually, I have combined all by data in an object and now I want to do post request and send all the data to the database :( but here I am facing a problem, which is not solved from yesterday. AXIOSERROR: Network Error. What is this actually ? There are several ways, which I could find in the stack overflow :) Same as replacing my locahost to IP addres, but that didn't worked for me. I have connected my android device to this application via expo go.

see pictures below

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVHJN.jpg)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgfgV.jpg)

Comment: expo bare or managed?